# addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument Selenium (Does not work)

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

I need to execute addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument method of Google Headless Chrome in C# .Net. I basically need to execute Javascript before any other javascript is executed on the documents. Here is my code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

    namespace User
    {
        class Program
        {
            //public static IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            public static IWebDriver driver;

            public static double magnification = 2;
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                //options.AddArgument("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument");
                options.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
                options.AddUserProfilePreference("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", "alert('INJECTED SCRIPT')");

                driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

                var action = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(driver);

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
         }
     }
```

But the alert isn't fired (i have tried other JavaScript code besides alert - nothing seems to work)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it might help someone:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
cmdParams.Add("source", "console.log('test')");
driver.ExecuteCdpCommand("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", cmdParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.After initialize the driver.Hope this will work.

```
  driver.ExecuteJavaScript("alert(0);")
```

OR

```
  driver.Scripts().ExecuteScript("alert(0);")
```

Comment: That does not execute script before others scripts on the page. It just executes your script after all of native scripts have finished working.

Comment: Plus it does not execute the script on all iframes on the page (something that Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument does)

Comment: @Phantom Have you found a way to do this? I am interested in this as welll

Answer (score 0):

I have only done this in Python but it should work the same way.

The chromedriver should expose a function named `execute_cdp_cmd()`
You can use this to run JavaScript before the page JavaScript is run. See the python example below. Note that you should add the code shown below **after** creating the driver but **before** you get the web page.

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
  "source": """
    alert(0);
  """
})
```

I don't have a C# example, but this might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V91.Page;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using RandomNameGeneratorLibrary;
using Network = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V91.Network;
using DevToolsSessionDomains = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V91.DevToolsSessionDomains;

IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;
session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
var domains = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<DevToolsSessionDomains>();
domains.Page.AddScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument(new AddScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocumentCommandSettings()
                {
                    Source = jscode,
                });
```